# Read key value from a table and update placeholders in a property file using maven

Tags: maven

I want to read key values from a table and replace the matching keys with values in a property file using maven

Comment: Could you please explain how you would use this in a build process? Which is the original problem you want to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not flexible when it comes to custom programming and I know no plugin combination which can do what you want. This is an advantage of Gradle. In Maven I would use the [Maven Exec Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and delegate the work to some external script, e.g. shell or Python script or you can use an embed a scripting language in Maven, like [Groovy](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute.html). There might be also a different plugin for your favorite scripting language.
The task in both approaches would then the read out the table, read the properties files and merge both.